# Unable to set date in angularUI datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

Following is the code in my member edit page(member-edit.html), in which I am getting the date for marriage anniversary and joining date from an API and setting it in `vm.member.marriage_anniversary` **&** `vm.member.joining_date` from `memberEditCtrl` controller.

In `vm.member.marriage_anniversary` I am getting value like this - **2016-06-23 18:30:00**

template code (**member-edit.html**)-

```
div class="form-group" ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
  <label>Marriage Anniversary:</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="vm.member.marriage_anniversary" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
  <label>Joining Date:</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="vm.member.joining_date" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
  </div>
</div>
```

My `DatepickerCtrl` code -

```
app.controller('DatepickerCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };

  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };

  $scope.toggleMin();
  $scope.maxDate = new Date(2020, 5, 22);

  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
  $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  $scope.events =
    [
      {
        date: tomorrow,
        status: 'full'
      },
      {
        date: afterTomorrow,
        status: 'partially'
      }
    ];

  $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  };
}]);
```

Though this datepicker is working fine on add case.

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @AbdoAdel It is throwing error in console `Error: this.activeDate.getFullYear is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it seems like you're getting a sql DateTime from your server, which doesn't behave well with angular (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4475)

Try to initally create a date object from your sql datetime ?

```
vm.member.marriage_anniversary = new Date(vm.member.marriage_anniversary)
```

Otherwise provide a full plunkr so I can help you more in depth, you can also create a filter or something that can do that for you with dates

Comment: Thx a lot, I did something like this - `vm.member.birthday = new Date(vm.member.birthday.split("-").join("/"));` which made the things working ..thx again